# Defining main with constant arguments (const int argc, const char * const argv[])?

Tags: c, arguments, constants, program-entry-point

In [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html), main is documented as either,

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
```

Or,

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
```

Can you define all the arguments as being `const` if you don't want to change them?

```
int main (const int argc, const char * const argv[])
```

Is it supported, unsupported, or illegal?

Comment: Note that top-level qualifers on function parameter types aren't part of the function declaration, so at least parts of your question aren't relevant.

Comment: @KerrekSB not irrelevant because I didn't know that. The question is well defined and if they're not part of the function declaration answer and I'll accept. I get typedef errors when arguments are not declared constant and you send them constant pointers, so I figured it was part of the typing.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, top-level constness still matters. Just not for purposes of prototyping, and hence how you're allowed to define `main`. Also, the const in "const char*" isn't top-level and matters very much.

Comment: Are you just curious or are you trying to solve a problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C, the implementation is allowed to support basically *any* type for the `main` function, so it may very well be that your particular implementation allows the various forms you have proposed. (And indeed it seems to allow the three-parameter version that exposes the environment.) However, the implementation is only *required* to accept the two forms

```
int main(void)
```

and

```
int main(int, char**)
```

Since `int(int, const char**)` isn't the same type as `int(int, char**)`, your proposed "constified" version is not strictly speaking required to be supported and falls under the first rule. It is, however, quite *likely* to work since `char*` and `const char*` are laid out the same way as far as the ABI is concerned, and the data you're given is mutable anyway.

Note further that `int f(int)` and `int f(const int)` are the *same* identical prototype, so there is no problem here regarding top-level qualifications of the parameters.

Comment: "Note further that `int f(int)` and `int f(const int)` are the same identical prototype" - How that? An implementation could used different ways to pass `const` and non-`const` parameters. Plase provide references to the standard supporting your claim.

Comment: @Olaf: In C, this is achieved via the notion of "compatible types"; all types of declarations of the same thing must be compatible (C11, 6.7p4). For compatibility of function types which includes the non-significance of top-level qualifiers, see 6.7.6.3p15. [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QitZ6D436yGG7SAz).

Comment: What about 6.7.3p10: "For two qualified types to be compatible, both shall have the **identically qualified version** of a compatible type". To me this reads like `int` and `const int` are not compatible, because hey are not identically qualified. As I pointed out above, this could make sense to allow additional optimisations (not that I have a specific implementation in mind, but SPARC or Hyperstone come to mind). I might not get the point, though, and I just have a problem with my wetware CPU cooler these days.